# TFS: How to set permissions per Work Item in a project?

Tags: tfs, workitem

Is there a way in TFS that user have permission to add Issue in a project and should not have permission to add/edit other work Items like User Story  etc ??

is there any extension or utility to do this on TFS ??

Answer (score 0):

You cannot restrict the editing of specific work item types. Permissions are controlled at the area path level. A user with permissions to create work items under an area path can create **any type** of work item under that area path.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such build-in configuration. It's also not able to use any extension or utility to do this on TFS.

Permissions for work items are based on the areas/iterations where they occur, and are set through the dialogue that defines areas and iterations.

In other words, you are **not able to set any permission either to a specific work item or work item type**.

You could submit a user voice [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/visual-studio-team-services.html?type=idea), our PM will kindly review your suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

There is only one out-of-box way to do this: [Create child nodes, modify work items under an area path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=azure-devops#set-permissions-area-path). You may try the following:

1. Create new team and area path for `Issues Team` [Add a team, move from one default team to several teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/add-teams?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser).
2. Edit Security for the Root Area Path and restrict edit work items for the `Issues Team`.
3. Edit Security for the `Issues Team` Area Path and allow to edit work items for the `Issues Team`.

In this case, your `Issues Team` can create and edit any work items under `Issues Team` Area Path, but can not edit any other work items.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question was about restricting the editing of specific work item **types**, not restricting who can edit work items period.

Comment: @DanielMann There is no options to restrict editing of specific work item types. Area Path is not a period (Iteration Path is a period). If you want to allow some users to edit some work item, assign that work item to Team Area Path.

Comment: @DanielMann I am understanding your question)) You can use Area Path to store your Issues and this is a way where you can manage Issues with separate  team members. This is not a direct option, this is a workaround.